# Joining multiple fields in a dataset joined with descriptions

Tags: sql, sql-server

First of all, let me state that we cannot control the structure of these tables, they are a third party solution, I'm just trying to create a query to get the data out in the way I specified.  The tables / query shown here are much-simplified to show the problem.

**Table 1**

CustomerFlag

```
CustomerID - int
Flag1 - bit
Flag2 - bit
Flag3 - bit
Flag4 - bit
Flag5 - bit
Flag6 - bit
...
```

The bits indicate which flags are set (1 = set, 0 = not set).

**Table 2**

FlagInformation

```
FlagNumber - int
FlagDescription - varchar
```

FlagNumber matches the field in CustomerFlag table, i.e.  FlagNumber 1 is for Flag1 in the CustomerFlag table.

What I'm trying to do is get a list of flags that are set for a customer along with the flag description.

Output should be:

```
CustomerID, FlagNumber, FlagDescription
```

Our current soltuion has a whole bunch of union queries.

```
select CustomerID, '1' as FlagNumber, FlagDescription
from CustomerFlag with (nolock)
left outer join FlagInformation
on FlagNumber = '1'
where Flag1 = 1
union all
select CustomerID, '2' as FlagNumber, FlagDescription
from CustomerFlag with (nolock)
left outer join FlagInformation
on FlagNumber = '2'
where Flag2 = 1
union all
select CustomerID, '3' as FlagNumber, FlagDescription
from CustomerFlag with (nolock)
left outer join FlagInformation
on FlagNumber = '3'
where Flag3 = 1
union all
...
```

It should be noted that this example is not complete - there's approximately 60 flag bits in the CustomerFlag table - and the current view has 60 unions to join them all.

I'm really wondering if there's a better way to do this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is definitely a better way.  Use `apply` and `join`:

```
select cf.customerid, fi.flagdescription
from customerflag cf
cross apply (values (1, cf.flag1),
             (2, cf.flag2),
             . . .  -- fill in the rest of the flags here
     ) v(flagnumber, value) join
     flaginformation fi
     on fi.flagnumber = v.flagnumber
where v.value = 1
```

Comment: Just a slight correction - second to last line "on fi.flagnumber = f.flagnumber" should be "on fi.flagnumber = v.flagnumber"